# None при парсинге JSON файлов requests python

Tags: python, json, парсер, requests

Моя цель: узнать скорости 5 кораблей
Я ожидал получить все скорости, но некоторые стали None.
Когда я проверял с помощью is none - будто код туда даже не заходил, ничего не происходило, а иногда выскакивали ошибки out of range

```
    import requests
import json

url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/'
response = requests.get(url).json()
starships_api = response.get('starships')


def check_planets(url):
    speedlist = []
    infolist = []
    for i in range(1, 5):
        response = requests.get(f'{url}/{i}').json()
        infolist.append({response.get('name'): response.get('max_atmosphering_speed')})
        speedlist.append(response.get('max_atmosphering_speed'))
    print(speedlist)
    print(infolist)


check_planets(starships_api)
```

Comment: а bs4 каким боком?

Comment: смотрите что у вас приходит в response